# How can i get a script readyState after window onload

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I want to append a script after to monitor other script's readyState.

How can i get  script、 image、 link 's readyState without add (onload, onreadystatechange)Event in head.(Because i can change nothing in html) .

note:

I can't add "onload" or "onreadystatechange"  event on other scripts. Because they have been loaded before i add Events. And i just to get the load status of them.

I try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].readyState
```

fail

Comment: sorry  without  add add (onload, onreadystatechange)Event in head.(Because i can change nothing in html) .

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan  I 've tried  "document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].readyState"   , but fail, it return undefined.